# index out of bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays

```
string[] scores = File.ReadAllLines(@"text file");
string score1 = scores[0];
```

The textfile contains the values 1-10 yet it keeps telling me the index is out of range.

why is this?

Comment: is this a valid path: `@"text file"`

Comment: Very simply because your scores array is initialized but empty, therefore you cannot access the first member of your array because it does not exist.  Have you made certain that ReadAllLines is doing what you think it is?

Comment: @erkaner yes it is the valid path

Comment: @DavidL i havent been able to check by breakpoints as it will crash at the first index value

Comment: You should be able to breakpoint your ReadAllLines line and see what happens. What do you mean it will crash at the first index value?

Comment: is that a valid file / file ext.. when you put a breakpont on score1 what is the value of scores..? can you show what the contents of the file looks like as well.. this should not be that difficult

Comment: i feel stupid now but restarting the program fixed it

Comment: kind of hard to believe ...but if you say so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadAllLines` is returning an array of length 0. Either your path to the file is bad or the file doesn't have what you expect in it. On the line where you index into 0 if you instead try printing the length of `scores` and you'll find it is 0.

In general you should be checking the length or using a foreach or for loop bound by the collections length so that you can avoid these types of exceptions. However, that being said, you need to follow that path and confirm whats in the file here. Keep in mind if you're using a relative path the Current working directory when the program is running might be different than what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\rearrange.txt");// whatever your name of file is and the location

The ReadAllLines does not know the exact location where to read the data from

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about the File Class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 1):

If it keeps telling you the index is out of range, it's probably because it actually is out of range - your array has length 0. Are you sure the contents of the file are what you think they are?

You should probably give the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) a thorough read.